# Codeigniter | Get previous URL and used as back button to previous page

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, redirect, back

I really wonder how can I do this, I have 3 pages that has the same link going to 1 page, now what I want to do is to have 1 button that is intelligently enough to get which of the 3 pages was used to go to that page and used it as it's link going back to that previous page.

Please if anyone who knows how to do this, help me to get out to this chaos. post some code how to do it in codeigniter. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Built in metho https://stackoverflow.com/a/70766040/13903942

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using a simple javascript to achieve previous button like,

```
<a href="javascript:window.history.go(-1);">Previous</a>
```

Comment: this is not really correct, the question is about codeigniter and besides, inline javascript is bad practice all in all. know there is a built in function that redirects back https://stackoverflow.com/a/70766040/13903942

Answer (score 5):

With the [url helper](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) loaded, set the current_url in a hidden field say 'refer_from'.

```
<input type="hidden" name="refer_from" value="<?php echo current_url(); ?>" />
```

Get this using [Input Class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html) and set this on the anchor link

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->input->post('refer_from'); ?>">Previous</a>
```

NOTE: using window.history.go(-1) will fail and throw a js error, if the user some how lands 
 directly on the "1" last page. window.history will be empty in that case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case jquery back methods means window.history etc,were not working so,I tried this hope this helps you guys.call this method on click. cheers

```
  function redirection()
        {
           <?php $send=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];?> 
            var redirect_to="<?php echo $send;?>";             
            window.location = redirect_to;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In **controller** add:

```
$data['back'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

In **view** add a button and link to `$back`.

Answer (score 0):

```
//to get previous url $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

<?php $send = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];?> 
var redirect_to="<?php echo $send;?>";    

//to redirected to this link
location.assign(redirect_to);

//you can pass static link also to redirected to this link
location.assign('facebook.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the older version, I guess there was such funcionallity but know there is and you should avoid use the accepted answer it may break in many ways.

Know you can use method [**`previous_url`**](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=anchor#previous_url).
Just add it where you need and is all done

```php
<div class="container">
    <a  href="<?= previous_url();?>" class="btn btn-info">
        <i class="bi bi-arrow-return-left"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

> Returns the full URL (including segments) of the page the user was previously on.

> Due to security issues of blindly trusting the **HTTP_REFERER** system variable, CodeIgniter will store previously visited pages in the session if it’s available. This ensures that we always use a known and trusted source. If the session hasn’t been loaded, or is otherwise unavailable, then a sanitized version of HTTP_REFERER will be used.

---

**EDIT**

### Improvements Issue fix

I noticed that the `previous_url` alone may suit for all scenarios, especially if we have a form which redirects back to the same page; that's because the previous page would be the one that the user was currently, hence will not come back in the desire place (and others solutions would have same issue anyway), a simple solution, and by all means improvable, is the following:

1. In `/app/Controllers/BaseController.php`

   ```php
    ///  Use this as base redirect
    public static $baseRedirect = '/index';

    /** @public
     *  Will check the User position and avoid and URL which aren't desired
     *  - @example
     *  Current Page: /news
     *  Previus : /index
     *
     * if the user update a form in the current page, which is a POST or GET and the user is
     * /news/update and then will go back to the current page now previous_url() will be /news and
     * NOT /index , if the user presses back will go to /news again and not /index.
     *
     * @var array $skip An array with url slugs to check the previous url, if the previous url containts any then skip to fallback
     * @var string $baseRedirect : base redirec if fallback is not provided
     * @param string|null $fallback use a target url as the desired 'Go Back' URL
     */
    public function getPreviousURL(?string $fallback=null)
    {
        // NOTE: We need the current_url also inside, to check that we don't go back in the same page ;)
        $skip = [current_url(), "create", "udate", "delete", "post"];
        $prev = previous_url();
        foreach($skip as $s) {
            if (str_contains($prev, $s)) {
                return site_url($fallback ? $fallback : self::$baseRedirect);
            }
        }
        return $prev;
    }
   ```
2. Now , in any controller which extends `BaseController`

   ```php
    class MyController extends BaseController
    // ... code 
    public function view($slug=null)
    {
        // code

        $data = [
            // data
            'prev' => $this->getPreviousURL(), // this will be available in any Controller 
        ];
        echo view('templates/header', $data);
        echo view('news/view', $data);
        echo view('templates/footer', $data);

    }
   ```

**Additionally you can pass any fallback into the url ;)**

```php
$data = [
            // data
            'prev' => $this->getPreviousURL(fallback: '/home'), // this will be available in any Controller
        ];
```

3. In a view `news/view.php`

---

```php
 <?php  $prev = $prev ??=  site_url('/index'); ?>

  <div class="container">
    <a  href="<?= $prev ?>" class="btn btn-info">
        G Back <i class="bi bi-arrow-return-left"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

/*Back button in codeigniter project using  jquery */

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"  id= "back">Back</button>
```

//JQuery of back button

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#back').on('click', function(){
        <?php $send = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];?> 
        var redirect_to="<?php echo $send;?>";             
        window.location.href = redirect_to;
      });
   });
  </script>
```